# (MVC) Html.DropDownList with viewbag error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to populate dropdownlist from sql database, but I get the following error:

> 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
string leaverulequery = "select ID,TypeDetail,LeaveType,Max from LeaveRule";
var leaver = db.LeaveRule.SqlQuery(leaverulequery).ToList();
var lists = new SelectList(leaverulequery, "ID", "TypeDetail");
ViewBag.CategoryId = lists;
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("lv_type", (SelectList) ViewBag.CategoryId, "--Select One--", new{  @class = "form-control input-sm"})
```

And my Model:

```
public class LeaveRule
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LeaveType { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public string TypeDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Please help guys, seems simple but i really cant get through this..
And i also want to ask can we filter what record from database populated to that dropdownlist with attribute LeaveType as reference? Thankyou

Comment: `new SelectList(leaver, "ID", "TypeDetail");` (not `leaverulequery`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string leaverulequery = "select ID,TypeDetail,LeaveType,Max from LeaveRule";
        var leaver = db.LeaveRule.SqlQuery(leaverulequery).ToList();
        var lists = new SelectList(leaver, "ID", "TypeDetail");
        ViewBag.CategoryId = lists;
```

In you code for selectedlist, the variable should be leaver. Not the leaverulequery